# Finding files older than x days on a system with a stripped down busybox

Tags: linux, files, find, date, busybox

I need to find and delete files older than 1 week in the Development unit. There are limited number utilities available on this unit. `-mtime` `find`'s predicate is not available. How do I check all files which are older than x days in this case?

Comment: It is unclear what you mean with "`mtime` is not available". It's not a utility whose name I recognise.

Comment: /path/to/my/folder$ find -type f -mtime +7 delete 
find: unrecognized: -mtime

Comment: share the distro of linux you are using.

Comment: @SivaPrasath Using busybox

Comment: https://github.com/google/cadvisor/issues/1556

Comment: It looks like it's busybox built without `FEATURE_FIND_MTIME`. Is `FEATURE_FIND_NEWER` enabled? Does `find -newer` work? Does your `test` utility or the `[` builtin of your `sh` support `-nt`?

Comment: Does `date +%s` work to retrieve the epoch time? How about `touch -d @1234` to set modification time of files based on epoch time?

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas Looks like busybox is built without FEATURE_FIND_MTIME or FEATURE_FIND_NEWER. I need to go back and check this to see if I can rebuild it with this.

Comment: You can work around this if you can use those `touch -d`/`date +%s` and `[ file -nt other-file ]`

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas I could rebuild busybox with FEATURE_FIND_MTIME and now I could delete files using -mtime. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`-mtime` is a standard predicate of `find` (contrary to `-delete`) but it looks like you have a stripped down version of `busybox`, where the `FEATURE_FIND_MTIME` feature has been disabled at build time.

If you can rebuild busybox with it enabled, you should be able to do:

```
find . -mtime +6 -type f -exec rm -f {} +
```

Or if `FEATURE_FIND_DELETE` is also enabled:

```
find . -mtime +6 -type f -delete
```

If not, other options could be to use `find -newer` (assuming `FEATURE_FIND_NEWER` is enabled) on a file that is set to have a one week old modification time.

```
touch -d "@$(($(date +%s) - 7 * 86400))" ../ref &&
  find . ! -type f -newer ../ref -exec rm -f {} +
```

Or if `-newer` is not available but `sh`'s `[` supports `-nt`:

```
touch -d "@$(($(date +%s) - 7 * 86400))" ../ref &&
  find . ! -type f -exec sh -c '
    for f do
      [ "$f" -nt ../ref ] || printf "%s\0" "$f"
    done' sh {} + |
    xargs -0 rm -f
```

Comment: Yes, busybox was a lighter version here. After re-build, `find . -mtime +6 -type f -exec rm {} \;` worked for me

Answer (score 2):

From `man find`:

> -atime n
>
> File was last accessed n*24 hours ago.  When find figures out how many 24-hour periods ago the file was last accessed, any fractional part is ignored, so to match -atime +1, a file has to have been  accessed  at  least
>                two days ago.
>
> -ctime n
>
> File's status was last changed n*24 hours ago.  See the comments for -atime to understand how rounding affects the interpretation of file status change times.

Depending on the use cases of the files you want to delete, these are your only other options for `find`. Why is `mtime` not available? What filesystem are you using? Did you explore any other options?

Comment: Asking more questions of the OP should be done as clarifying *comments*, not *answers*.